# Prevent mysql injection and xss atack

Tags: mysql, xss, code-injection

I'm looking for a good solution to prevent mysql injection and xss atack. I've read a lot of subjects but is unclear for me.

I only want to permit some bb codes like [b],[i],[u]. That's all.

Can you please tell me if this is ok :

```
<?php
$escape = array('input_one','input_two','get_ids_from_url','etc');

foreach($escape as $input)
{
    if(isset($_POST[$input])) 
    {$_POST[$input] = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$input]), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'));}
    if(isset($_GET[$input])) 
    {$_GET[$input] = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_GET[$input]), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'));}
}
?>
```

Comment: If you want to prevent SQL injection, [you should use PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). It isn't fool proof, but it's way safer than the `mysql_` functions.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing here is escaping on input for two different uses: HTML and MySQL. Don't do that; magic quotes was removed for a reason.

What you should be doing is escaping where you actually use the variables, and in the case of database access, using PDO or MySQLi instead of the nearly-deprecated and just generally bad `mysql_` family of functions.